# SVG stretch with parent DIV

Tags: svg

I am trying to make SVG responsive, so when window is re-sized, my svg will resize as well and fill parent div as it is when viewed first time.

Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nhe613kt/321/

**HTML**

```
<div id="myConta">
    <div id="myContaList"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(window).resize(OwResize);

function OwResize() {
    $("#myConta").height(window.innerHeight - (window.innerHeight / 40));
}

var sideRectW = window.innerWidth / 20,
    sideRectH = window.innerHeight / 20,
    width = window.innerWidth - (window.innerWidth / 50),
    height = window.innerHeight - (window.innerHeight / 40),
    boxW = (width - sideRectW) / 4,
    boxH = (height - sideRectH) / 4,
    boxSize = boxW + boxH,
    xPos1 = sideRectW,
    xPos2 = boxW + sideRectW,
    xPos3 = (boxW * 2) + sideRectW,
    xPos4 = (boxW * 3) + sideRectW,
    yPos1 = 0,
    yPos2 = boxH,
    yPos3 = boxH * 2,
    yPos4 = boxH * 3;

var CreateRect = function (x, y, boxColor, boxId) {
    svgContainer.append("rect")
        .attr("x", x)
        .attr("y", y)
        .attr("id", "rectBox" + boxId)
        .attr("width", boxW)
        .attr("height", boxH)
        .attr("fill", boxColor)
        .attr("class", "hover_group")
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMaxYMid meet")
        .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + $("#myConta").width() + $("#myConta").height())
        .attr("onclick", "alert('haha');");
};
var CreateRectWithLength = function (x, y, w, h, boxColor) {
    svgContainer.append("rect")
        .attr("x", x)
        .attr("y", y)
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
        .attr("fill", boxColor);
};
var CreateText = function (x, y, text, textColor, size) {
    svgContainer.append("text")
        .attr("x", x)
        .attr("y", y)
        .attr("fill", textColor)
        .attr("font-size", size)
        .text(text);
};
var CreateText90 = function (x, y, text, textColor, size) {
    svgContainer.append("text")
        .attr("x", x)
        .attr("y", y)
        .attr("fill", textColor)
        .attr("font-size", size)
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90," + x + 20 + ", " + y + ")")
        .text(text);
};
var svgContainer = d3.select("#myConta")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("id", "myContasvg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("fill", "#2E2E2E")
    .attr("float", "right")
    .append("g");

CreateRectWithLength(0, 0, sideRectW, window.innerHeight, "Black");
CreateRectWithLength(0, height - sideRectH, width, sideRectH, "Black");

CreateText90(0, yPos3, "Sales", "white", 16);
CreateText(xPos3, height - sideRectH / 5, "Profit", "white", 16);

CreateText(sideRectW / 2, yPos1 + (boxH / 2), "3", "white", 12);
CreateText(sideRectW / 2, yPos2 + (boxH / 2), "2", "white", 12);
CreateText(sideRectW / 2, yPos3 + (boxH / 2), "1", "white", 12);
CreateText(sideRectW / 2, yPos4 + (boxH / 2), "0", "white", 12);

CreateText(xPos1 + (boxW / 2), height - sideRectH / 2, "0", "white", 12);
CreateText(xPos2 + (boxW / 2), height - sideRectH / 2, "1", "white", 12);
CreateText(xPos3 + (boxW / 2), height - sideRectH / 2, "2", "white", 12);
CreateText(xPos4 + (boxW / 2), height - sideRectH / 2, "3", "white", 12);

CreateRect(xPos1, yPos1, "#C0FC3E", 03);
CreateRect(xPos1, yPos2, "#60FC60", 02);
CreateRect(xPos1, yPos3, "#64FE2E", 01);
CreateRect(xPos1, yPos4, "#00FF00", 00);

CreateRect(xPos2, yPos1, "#F6FF33", 13);
CreateRect(xPos2, yPos2, "#AFFC3B", 12);
CreateRect(xPos2, yPos3, "#00FF00", 11);
CreateRect(xPos2, yPos4, "#64FE2E", 10);

CreateRect(xPos3, yPos1, "#FDB500", 23);
CreateRect(xPos3, yPos2, "#8DB723", 22);
CreateRect(xPos3, yPos3, "#AFFC3B", 21);
CreateRect(xPos3, yPos4, "#60FC60", 20);

CreateRect(xPos4, yPos1, "red", 33);
CreateRect(xPos4, yPos2, "#FDB500", 32);
CreateRect(xPos4, yPos3, "#F6FF33", 31);
CreateRect(xPos4, yPos4, "#C0FC3E", 30);



var rectContainer = d3.selectAll("#rectBox33");
var rectX = rectContainer.attr("x");
console.log(rectX);
```

**Please Note**
This is not exact what I am working on, but I tried to make it as close to working example as I could.

**What I don't want**

[image]

I want svg to resize and fill parent div automatically on window size.

Comment: Can you explain what you are actually trying to achieve exactly?  I can't really tell from your code.  Plus there are some obvious mistakes, such as why you are setting `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` on a `<rect>`?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I am new to SVG so please point out what wrong I am doing, I just want to make this svg responsive and resize to fill parent div

Comment: The `<rect>` element does not have those two attributes.  They belong on the `<svg>` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you were after, but how is this?

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhe613kt/317/)

You need to apply the `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` attributes to your SVG.  Also if you want the SVG to scale with its parent `<div>` then you should not set the width and height to fixed values. Instead leave them unset so that the default to the value "100%".

Comment: Thanks Paul, but your example is not stretching svg to fill the space, I made it more clear here - http://jsfiddle.net/nhe613kt/321/

Comment: Oh, you mean stretch in both width and height?  Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/nhe613kt/324/

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted, but what did you changed, could you add explaination to your answer please and I will accept it, thanks.

Comment: I noticed it adds scrolls to left and right of whole screen even though it fits to the screen, any idea

Comment: sorry not left and right, it's right and bottom of screen, thanks

Comment: The change I made was to use `preserveAspectRatio="none"`.  As for the cause of the scrollbar, I imagine it is because, at smaller heights, your `<body>` margin is becoming greater than the (height/40).  It would be better to remove the margin, ie. `BODY { margin: 0; }` instead of using that fudge factor.

Comment: Please explain what you mean. It worked when I tried it.  To make sure no rounding errors cause scroll bars to appear, you can also add `overflow: hidden`. http://jsfiddle.net/nhe613kt/364/

Comment: I had to add overflow: hidden to svg, thanks for putting in right direction, however they were added because of "text" any text tag to svg for some reason i can't think of, thanks though